# ArcGIS Pro 3 Create year, month and day columns

Tags: arcgis-pro, date, datetime

Based on the sample data column below, what tool I can use in ArcGIS Pro 3 to create the `Year`, `Month` and `Day` columns in the attribute table?

The purpose is to then use these columns to create a `space time cube`.

Please note that I am not looking for a `Python` script based solution, as I know this can be easily done in `R`. I am looking for a `tool` or a `model builder` based solution` (if necessary).

Sample data:

```
1/27/2021 4:48:45 PM
12/30/2020 8:59:58 PM
12/24/2020 9:18:21 PM
1/22/2021 10:38:24 PM
12/18/2020 9:12:52 AM
1/28/2021 9:26:15 AM
```

Comment: You're not "looking" for a python script solution, but using a python interpreter in field calculator would probably be your best approach.  Model Builder is a GUI for python, and there is no tool that just does this.  Create three new fields, one for each date parameter.  The field calculator can be used to get the date parameters, and if your input values are stored in a date type field, it's very easy.  Year is !datefield!.year, Month is !datefield!.month and Day is !datefield!.day.  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105804/extract-month-from-date-in-python

Comment: @evv_gis, cheers, that works, if you want you can add this as an answer.

Comment: @evv_gis, for some reason now the `space time cube` tool is not picking up these new columns under `Time Field`. Could there be a reason for this? Do I need to merge these new `columns` into a new `Date` column?

Comment: First time looking at the Create Space Time Cube by Aggregating Points, and it looks like your input above would work as long as the data is stored in a date type field.  There doesn't appear to be a need to split out the year, month, and day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new fields in your field designer for each field, year, month, and day.  Then use the field calculator to calculate each value using the python interpreter, respectively.
`!datefield!.year`, `!datefield!.month`, and `!datefield!.day`.